# What is difference between cURL and libcurl?

Tags: curl

I am unable to install this WP plugin

```
http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/video-thumbnails
```

Because it keeps telling me that

```
Sorry, but this plugin requires libcurl to be activated on your server.
```

I am using WAMP and cURL is activated.

I do not understand what is the difference between cURL and libcurl, that this plugin is talking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cURL is the package, and can include both the command line curl.exe application and the libcurl DLL "library", the latter one being something that's used by other applications.